# an error while configuring the PyTorch environment variables in the Ubuntu system

Tags: python, ubuntu, deep-learning, pytorch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuBIb.png)

When I try to configure the PyTorch environment variables(. configure.sh --use_pytorch), I encounter the following error. Anyone know how to resolve it?

I encountered an issue while installing DeepFlame. This problem has been troubling me for over a week now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.